# Fatal error: Call to a member function fields() on a non-object

Tags: database

I have the following code that is throwing an error:

```
/**
 * Custom content function
 * 
 * Get system status from the helpdesk database
 * 
 * @return
 *   An key => value pairing of systems and their status
 */
function system_status_sjhc_status_check() {
    //connection info for the helpdesk database
    $helpdeskDB = array(
            'database' => 'mydb',
            'username' => 'myuser', 
            'password' => 'mypass', 
            'host' => 'myhost', 
            'driver' => 'mysql', 
    );
    Database::addConnectionInfo('helpdeskDB', 'default', $helpdeskDB);
    db_set_active('helpdeskDB');

    //grab the current light status
    $result = db_select('hd_lights', 'l')
        ->fields('l')
        ->leftJoin('hd_status', 's', 'l.id = s.id')
        ->fields('s', array('stamp', 'message'))
        ->orderBy('`order`', 'ASC')
        ->execute();

    db_set_active(); // without the paramater means set back to the default for the site

    return $result;
}
```

The error I'm receiving is:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fields() on a non-object

and its being thrown on this line:

```
    ->fields('s', array('stamp', 'message'))
```

I can't figure out what I've done wrong, everything looks OK to me and the code runs fine without the join and additional table fields.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`SelectQuery::join()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3Ajoin/7), [`SelectQuery::leftJoin()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQueryInterface%3A%3AleftJoin/7) etc. don't return the query (they return the alias to the created JOIN), so they can't be chained.

Just separate your code out like this:

```
$query = db_select('hd_lights', 'l')
  ->fields('l')
  ->fields('s', array('stamp', 'message'))
  ->orderBy('`order`', 'ASC');

$query->leftJoin('hd_status', 's', 'l.id = s.id');

$result = $query->execute();
```

Comment: I'm grateful too ! Got crazy before reading your answer...

Answer (score 1):

This is how you suppose to write db_select with join (leftJoin in your case)

```
   //grab the current light status
    $result = db_select('hd_lights', 'l')
        ->fields('l');
    $result->leftJoin('hd_status', 's', 'l.id = s.id');
    $result->fields('s', array('stamp', 'message'))
        ->orderBy('`order`', 'ASC')
        ->execute();
```